# I need to know this about fire sprinklers for my fire year project

Tags: structural-engineering

do structural engineers consider the dead load of the pipe and the water inside the pile when design buildings? how is it done

Comment: Probably total mass. What pile? Nuclear?

Comment: @SolarMike would that be heavy water then? ... lol

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the weight of the pipe and the content must be included in the design of the supporting structures, which can be a beam/truss/joist, the slabs, or a pipe rack. The pipe is considered fully filled in normal operating conditions and treated as a uniformly distributed load on the horizontal runs, a concentrated load on the joint of a vertical run.

On top of the static weight, the thrust due to the flow, including start-up and sudden shut-down, at the bends must also be considered, as well as the inertia forces induced by a seismic event.